# Можно ли превратить часть столбца в таблице mysql в отдельный столбец?

Tags: mysql

Существует таблица вида:

```
 id | date  | value
----+-------+-------
  1 | 21-01 |    10
  2 | 21-01 |    20
  3 | 22-01 |    10
  4 | 22-01 |    20
  3 | 23-01 |    10
  4 | 23-01 |    20
```

Нужно ее превратить в таблицу вида:

```
  date | value | date 2 | value2 | date 3 | value3
-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------
 21-01 |    10 |  22-01 |     10 |  23-01 |     10
 21-01 |    20 |  22-01 |     20 |  23-01 |     20
```

Можно ли это сделать SQL запросом? Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: ищите по "mysql pivot"

Comment: Это определённо "сводная таблица" или "пивот". Но в вашем примере непонятен принцип по которому вы группируете значения по строкам. Неужели по полю `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае нет, нельзя. SQL не предназначен для "работы по горизонтали". Но в частном случае можно применить [трюк](http://artoodetoo.ru/conditional-aggregates/#more-233): если вы заранее знаете значения, распределяемые по горизонтали, то есть набор колонок предопределён.

Уловка состоит в группировке + наборе условных функций по одной на каждое вычисляемое значение.

Буквально ответ как у вас можно получить таким образом:

```
SELECT
  '21-01' as `date`,
  SUM(IF(`date`='21-01', `value`, NULL)) AS `value`,
  '22-01' as `date2`,
  SUM(IF(`date`='22-01', `value`, NULL)) AS `value2`,
  '23-01' as `date3`,
  SUM(IF(`date`='23-01', `value`, NULL)) AS `value3`
FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY `value`
```

Но возможно вам надо группировать по какому-то другому полю. С одинаковыми значениями value* строки выглядят как-то бессмысленно.